# how to pass php variables in a url, present inside a php function

Tags: php, curl

i have a while loop which collects data from a mysql table, inserts them into php variables. These php variables are passed as parameters to a url present inside a php function. Apparently the url does not pick the values of php variables. Need help with this. The code looks like this.

```
<?php
include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');
$link=mysql_connect("160.60.20.100","vcpm","abcd");
mysql_select_db("vcpm");

$GMT='2017-04-23 00:59';
$MinusOne='2017-04-23 00:00';

$query="SELECT fraud_id,stat_id from Hasoffers where fraud_id IS NOT NULL AND stat_datetime between '".$MinusOne."' AND '".$GMT."';";
$pl=mysql_query($query);
$count=mysql_num_rows($pl);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($pl))
{
    $conversion_id=$row['stat_id'];

    $fraud_category=$row['fraud_id'];

    echo ip($conversion_id,$fraud_category).PHP_EOL;
}

function ip($conversion_id,$fraud_category)
{
    $conversion_id= $argv[1];
    $fraud_category= $argv[2];

    $url="https://api.hasoffers.com/Apiv3/json?NetworkId=mxpresso&Target=Conversion&Method=updateMeta&NetworkToken=NETY5hP42BJX8KJlTmTQfsjTo1Rq1m&id=".$conversion_id."&data[note]=".$fraud_category;
        echo $url;

        //  Initiate curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Disable SSL verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    //Will return the response, if false it print the response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    // Set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    // Execute
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    // Closing
    curl_close($ch);
}

?>
```

Comment: can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: $conversion_id= $argv[1];
$fraud_category= $argv[2];
What are these?
You can directly use arguments inside function by name

Comment: To pass them as arguments inside the url

Comment: You need to find out / specify for us what way of submission that API actually expects, _how_ the values should be handed over. Programming is not a guessing game, but the implementation of specific details.

Comment: @SahilGulati i do not get n error. But when i echo $url it does not show any values where i placed the variables in the url

Comment: comment $conversion_id= $argv[1]; $fraud_category= $argv[2]; and retry

Comment: @AmitChahal Remove these lines   ` $conversion_id= $argv[1];
    $fraud_category= $argv[2];` these are over-writting your parameters

Comment: Did you try http_build_query() ? It may help in your case, i guess.

Comment: Listen to @AbhishekSharma. Remove those 2 lines as they are wasting time. When you try again, put this as the first line of your function: `print "conversion_id: $conversion_id; fraud_category:  $fraud_category";`. This will dump your parameters to see whether there’s anything there to start with.

Comment: Meanwhile, add the following line to the beginning of your `while` loop: `print_r($row);` to see what data you are getting from your database. This and my previous comment are common steps in trouble shooting: print the data you think you’re working with.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "NetworkId=mxpresso&Target=Conversion&.........");
```

Does it help?

Comment: This is just a wild guess, it should have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
$conversion_id= $argv[1];
$fraud_category= $argv[2];
```

is probably your issue.
the `$argv` array is used when you want to be able to call pages from the command line [see doc](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

you are actually overriding the parameters you pass to the function from MySql and that's the problem.

comment both lines and try echoing the url

Answer (score 0):

Assumed you implemented the correct url/url variable names etc, drop the following:

```
$conversion_id= $argv[1];
$fraud_category= $argv[2];
```

$argv[1]/$argv[2] overwrite the value you get from the supplied parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ip` function you are overloading `$conversion_id` and `$fraud _category` with $argv[1](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) and $argv[2].
$argv is used when you pass argumnents to a php script from command line

[PHP argv manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

Refer to this documentation for $argv usage